# How do I draw this arrow in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw the arrows below in a tikz figure. This could probably be easily drawn using the `\draw` and `controls` functions, however it'll be a little bit messy as I would be using the arrows in several places.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);

\draw[-,thick] (A) --++ (45:1cm);
\draw[-,thick] (A) --++ (315:1cm);

\draw[-,thick] ($(A) + (45:5mm)$)  --++ (3,0);
\draw[-,thick] ($(A) + (315:5mm)$) --++ (3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Minimum working example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you want to use the arrows? Inside a tikz picture? or somewhere else in the document? Maybe you could add a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter In a tikz picture obviously.

Comment: @iab not a very constructive response, but maybe sam has been misunderstood: do you intend to use it as unique element of a  tikzpicture or as an element of a more complex tikzpicture? Anyhow, for the second arrow, arrow type `implies` on a double line could be what you need.

Comment: -1 from me for your question and for your response to Samcarter

Comment: @ChristophFrings It's a unique element on a more complex tikzpicture. However, it's really the arrow type I'm interested in. I don't think a MWE will really add much useful information to the question.

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for letting me know :) For some reason, the website still hasn't shown your down vote.

Comment: Creating this arrow is very easy... if you want to just create the arrow. But if you want to use it in various ways then things get complicated. @samcarter 's first question was about this: where do you want to use it? How? A proper example to show its use would be preferable. Even a mock-up picture would be helpful, but a better way would be to have an example code where you want to add the arrow, while telling how you want to implement it.

Comment: @Alenanno An MWE has been included. Hope it is clear now what I want to do? A mock-up had also been included in the original question. I'm sure there would be a niftier way to do this?

Comment: That's actually a good example why a MWE is helpfull, if not necessary to understand your question! I guess we all assumed your are drawing an arrow (and don't puzzle it together from individual lines) and are looking for a shorter way like defining an tikz style or something ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read the section "16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips" in the tikz manual

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=1pt, double distance=3pt, -{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to make the arrow as wide as the one in the MWE? Adjusting `line width` in your example only makes the lines thicker which is not what I'm after. A similar shape to what I'm after is the `single arrow` node type.

Comment: @iab have you tried adjusting `double distance=3pt`?